# ¿Es redundante "sine qua non" e "ineludible" en la misma frase?

Tags: gramática, latinismo

En un artículo de un periodico online [dice](https://www.elespectador.com/noticias/el-mundo/maduro-todo-el-que-vote-el-domingo-estara-reconociendo-la-constituyente-articulo-717728):

> "La ANC decidió que los gobernadores que el pueblo va a elegir (...) para poder asumir sus cargos, tendrán que juramentarse y subordinarse a la ANC como requisito sine qua non, ineludible. (...)"

En la RAE existe una entrada para *sine qua non*:

> [*sine qua non*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Xy7q3lU)
>
> Loc. lat.; literalmente 'sin la cual no'.

¿Es redundante usar la expresión *sine qua non* para hablar de un requisito y además decir que es ineludible? ¿No está implícito ya que es ineludible?

Comment: Do you think they are trying to be helpful to people who do not immediately understand the Latin phrase?

Comment: @mdewey what you say makes sense. Indeed I had to look for that expression on internet. However that makes me wonder, why, in the first place, do they use an expression they suspect won't be immediately understand...

Comment: Well it is hard to be sure but some people think that being obscure makes them look clever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yo estoy de acuerdo (al menos parcialmente) con @mdewey. En mi opinión están haciendo una aclaración por si no se entiende, o quizás incluso para darle más énfasis a la expresión. Poner dos adjetivos sinónimos o con significado cercano puede servir para eso mismo en otros contextos:

> Se compró un bolso horrible, feísimo.

Otro:

> Ayer hizo un día precioso, espectacular.

Me parece particularmente acertado el uso de la coma para separar ambos adjetivos. Si se utilizase un "y" sí que me parecería redundante y que el redactor no tiene mucha confianza en que esté usando correctamente una expresión bastante formal.

Por otra parte, tampoco parece mal adjetivar *requisito* con palabras como *indispensable* o *ineludible*. También refuerza el carácter obligatorio de la condición o requisito en cuestión.

Comment: Esto me recuerda un caso que leí hace poco en SO: [Alguien dijo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13671820/1983854): _You don't need (...) when declaring (...) It's redundant and superfluous_ a lo que [otro comentó](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671710/jquery-form-validation-on-button-click/13671820#comment49726657_13671820) inteligentemente: _I think it's ironic that you say both superfluous and redundant_. :)